# Why does image slider load the images horizontally instead of a slide?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I have used **owl.carousel.js.**

On page I have this:

```
<div id="home-slider" class="home-slider">
</div>
```

Via ajax and jquery I am looping through the collection of images and trying to slide but it repeats each image horizontally instead of sliding.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var url = '@Url.Action("getImages", "Gallery")'; 
    var data = ''

    $.get(url, data, function (response) {
        $.each(response, function (i, val) {
            $("#home-slider").append("<div id=\"" + 'Outdiv' + i + "\" class='item home-slider-bg'></div>");
            var url = '../Content/images/' + val.Image;
            $("#Outdiv" + i).attr("style", "background-image:url(\""+url +"\")");
        });
    });
});
```

Why?

Update:

Everything is fine If I add a div with class='item home-slider-bg, manually and set it's background-image then it works, like this:

```
<div id="home-slider" class="home-slider">
    <div class="item home-slider-bg" style="background-image: url('/Content/images/slider-1.jpg')"> 
                </div>
    <div class="item home-slider-bg" style="background-image: url('/Content/images/slider-2.jpg')">

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Let me just load your code and imagine the css into my brain browser a second... nope, css would still be useful. an interactive example even better

Comment: @DominicTobias: everything is fine, If I add a div with class='item home-slider-bg, manually and set it's background-image then it works

Comment: @DominicTobias check the updated question